# esttab label i. factor variable

Tags: label, stata

I am having a strange issue where one version of Stata (14.1 on Mac) exhibits different behavior than another version (14.0 on PC). I run this code:

```
sysuse auto, clear
gen a = "abc"
replace a = "def" if _n>60
replace a = "ghi" if _n<15
encode a, gen(b)
eststo clear
eststo: reg price i.b 
esttab
esttab, label
```

The difference comes in what is displayed with the last line of code, `esttab, label`. On the map, the value labels appear. On the PC, the same labels as in the `esttab` appear - `1b.b, 2.b, 3.b` as opposed to `abc, def, ghi` as on the Mac.

How can I get the PC version to exhibit the same behavior as the Mac. Are there any alternative approaches to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you checked that you have the same version of `esttab` installed in both computers?
type `adoupdate` to update everything.

Comment: You can use `which esttab` to see the version.

Comment: The one is from 2015 and the other from 2009, so it looks like this is the problem.